# Converting int to varchar data type in MySQL

Tags: mysql, casting, int, varchar

I have two tables. I need to compare two values but they are in different datatype in both the tables. In one table, it  is int and in another table it is varchar. I tried using varchar with cast(), but cast() does not work with varchar.

My query is like following:

```
select user.username, user_follow.object_id from user,user_follow
left join user_follow
ON cast(user_follow.object_id as varchar(25))= user.username
WHERE user.username= cast(user_follow.object_id as varchar(25));
```

Help please.
thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"**does not work**" is not a precise description of the observed behavior.

We expect MySQL to "work" according to the specification. The behavior we expect is for MySQL to return a specific error message, such as

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near VARCHAR
```

We expect MySQL to return that error message because according to the MySQL Reference Manual, **`VARCHAR`** is not a valid type for `CAST`, but **`CHAR`** is a valid type.

Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

---

NOTE:

There are some other problems with the query.

There appear to be two references to the `user_follow` table. At least one of those references will need to have a table alias assigned.

The query is also using old-school comma syntax for a join operation, mixed with a join operation is using the newer JOIN keyword.

Without a specification of the resultset to be returned, we can only guess at which queries will satisfy the requirements.

```
  SELECT u.username
       , f.object_id
    FROM user u
    LEFT
    JOIN user_follow f 
      ON CONVERT(CHAR(25),f.object_id) = u.username
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `cast` as a `CHAR` datatype, there is no `varchar` datatype that you can cast data to, anyway try this please:)
Not sure what you want to use, `left join` or `join`.

```
select u.username, uf.object_id from user u
left join user_follow uf
ON cast(uf.object_id as char(25))= cast(u.username as char(25))
-- WHERE cast(u.username as char(25)) = cast(uf.object_id as char(25));
```

Or

```
select u.username, uf.object_id from user u, user_follow uf
-- left join user_follow uf
-- ON cast(uf.object_id as char(25))= cast(u.username as char(25))
WHERE cast(u.username as char(25)) = cast(uf.object_id as char(25));
```

And take a look of [function_cast](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: I have tried using the above query but it is giving me an error. error code:1066. Not unique table/alias: 'user_follow'

Comment: Updated, please check it again.

Comment: And if I'm using alias, i still get error. Error 1054: Unknown column 'u.username' in 'on clause'. my query is-    select u.username, uf.object_id 
FROM user AS u,user_follow AS uf
LEFT
JOIN user_follow
ON cast(uf.object_id as char(25))= cast(u.username as char(25))
WHERE cast(u.username as char(25)) = cast(uf.object_id as char(25));

Comment: @JyotKhanguraChahal Check my answer one more time please. You shoud use one of `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`, take a look of [9.2.1.9 LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html).

Comment: I run your 1st query. It's running. :) but the username field have names and object id field is NULL . I tell you about problem specification. In user table, I have user's personal details. In user_follow table, I have details about users who are following other users. I just have the id (int) of users in user_follow table. I need to match the ids with user names.

Comment: @JyotKhanguraChahal How about running my 2nd query. Or you can give us some simple data and desired result.

Comment: 2nd query is running also. But the resulting table is empty. I want to put the screen shots of the ER diagram here, but can't do so.

Comment: @JyotKhanguraChahal How about sample data and your desired result? Use post's format of SO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CONCAT(user_follow.object_id)